# Test for series Convergence:$\sum^{\infty}_{n=2}{\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n-1}\right)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to test for this series Convergence:
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=2}{\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n-1}\right)}$$
I'm wondering which method should i use?

Comment: Hint: for $x$ near $1$, we have $\ln(x) \sim x -1$ so for large $n$, $\ln\left( \frac{n+1}{n-1}\right) \sim \frac 2{n-1}$.

Comment: @User8128 can you explain to me how can i use this hint to test for convergence?

Comment: @Arjang actually it converges

Comment: @Arjang yes but i need to proof, how can you see it?

Comment: @Tel0s using my above comment, the summand is asymptotic to $1/n^{3/2}$ so the sum coverages by the comparison test/$p$-series test.

Comment: @Arjang http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20ln%28%28n%2B1%29%2F%28n-1%29%29%2Fsqrt%28n%29%2C%20n%3D2..infinity

Comment: @User8128 i got what are u trying to say it converges, i just did it, thank u

Comment: @User8128 : thank you, that is awesome link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the comparison test.

Note that for $x > 0$ we have that $\ln(x) \leq x-1$.  Hence $\ln (\frac{n+1}{n-1}) \leq \frac{n+1}{n-1} -1 = \frac{2}{n-1}$.

Hence, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \ln(\frac{n+1}{n-1}) \leq \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}(n-1)}$ so the series converges by the comparison test and the $p$-test.

Comment: First, you have $\ln(x)\le x-1$ but then you switch to $\ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n-1}\right)\le1-\frac{n+1}{n-1}$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales corrected, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.